# Unable to find direct url for unlisted app

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We have an unlisted app in google workspace marketplace. In the Google Cloud Platform admin, in the API & Services for Google Workspace Marketplace SDK in the App Integration section, where we have our app checked as Unlisted, it says:
"Unlisted application won't be shown in browse or search results. It can only be accessed by the direct URL."

We are trying to figure out where we find the direct URL. If you know where this is found, please let me know. We tried to guess it by forming an url by looking at a listed app we have but that did not work.

Regards,
LT

Comment: For the listed app, we see the direct url in the Store Listing page but since the unlisted app is Unpublished, I suppose that's why there is no direct url. The problem is that the app is an internal app that supposed to only be used by google workspace accounts (domains) that we own. The app can't be private because we need to use it on more than one google workspace account (domain). I believe we try to get it published but was denied at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Check the status of your app

- go on https://console.cloud.google.com/ and select the project where your app is located
- go on `Google Workspace Marketplace SDK` (e.g. by typing it into the search field) adn select `Manage`
- Select in the left side menu `Store listing`

Depending on the publication status of your app you will see one of the following screens:

---

---

- `Approved` with the URL to the Addon

[image]

---

---

- `Unpublished`

[image]

In this case you need to fill out all the necessary fields and go on `Publish`

[image]

---

---

- `Unpublished (Rejected)`

[image]

In this case you should have received an email from the reviewers explaining you why the app has been rejected. If you cannot find the email - try to publish again and you will receive a new email from the reviewers.

---

---

**IMPORTANT:**

Until your app is published  - there will be no URL to its listing - since it will not be listed before the publishing process is completed.

Comment: If that's the case, then how can you test the installation experience?